# PHP Mcrypt and HTML5 Crypto API encryption/decryption

Tags: javascript, php, html, encryption, aes

I need to exchange a series of keys for an external platform through a webpage, may happens that user has not a SSL cert configured for use HTTPS so for do it in a secure way before starting the transfer I send a confirmation code to the user mail box, with this code I generate a SHA-256 hash (done with PHP and HTML5 Crypto API) and I use this as key for AES-256 (CBC) encryption of the string with keys, after that I convert it in base64 and send to the client that will convert it into file and triggers download. The problem is that I can't convert the components (the IV is connected to the encrypted string) into the format requested by JavaScript. Here the decryption code:

```
string = window.atob(string);
promise_key = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: "AES-CBC", length: 256}, false, ["decrypt"]);
promise_key.then(function(key){
    key_object = key;
    var vector = string.substr(0, 16);
    string = string.substr(16);
    decrypt_promise = window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "AES-CBC", iv: vector, length: 256}, key_object, string);
    decrypt_promise.then(function(result){
        decrypted_data = new Uint8Array(result);
        console.log(decrypted_data);
    });
});
```

Process:

1. Client sends an AJAX request to the server for init the key generation;
2. Server send a confirmation numeric code to user mail box and an ID to AJAX;
3. User receives the e-mail message, writes code into web page and submits it;
4. Client sends an AJAX request for the step 2 with the reveived ID;
5. Server checks ID, generates and encrypts keys and sends them to the client;
6. Client prepares the decryption key hashing the e-mail code with SHA-256 (also the server done this for encryption);
7. Client decrypts keys, build a JSON string and trigger the download as file.

Comment: I wish I understood what you think you are doing. You may have to make it clearer what is exactly going on here and the order in which client and server do things to get a decent answer here

Comment: When I request the key generation the server sends the email and an ID as JSON response, after that the user writes the numeric code from email to the webpage which will send a request to the server for the second step with the ID and it will response with the encrypted string, after that I try to decrypt it with the JS code which I posted. The PHP encryption works because I used Mcrypt sometimes but JS doesn't like the data type passed as IV and string. If can be helpful I can post also the PHP code.

Comment: No edit your question, its easier to read than a comment

Comment: Done, I hope that will be clear enough

Comment: What do you need exactly? The part which doesn't work is the posted JavaScript, if you want I can post an example of an encrypted string or maybe put the example string together with the code into JSFiddle.

Comment: Luckly the cryptography works, it's JavaScript that doesn't accept the string because I done many time operation like this with PHP and all works, except some null chars to strip, but it's the first time that I use these APIs, sorry if I'm not so clear.

Comment: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: I know that JavaScript it's bad for cryptography but I've not so much choices